# JS slice last element DESC

Tags: javascript, slice

I have array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
How to get last 3 elements **6, 5, 4** by DESC

I use **slice** but I get the items in the wrong order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you want to reverse the array you have sliced.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let newArr = arr.slice(-3).reverse(); 
console.log(newArr)
```

if your last 3 elements are not in ascending order already in the original array you can use sort after slice. Well you can use sort for your original problem as well

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6]

let newArr2 = arr.slice(-3).sort((a,b)=>b-a);
console.log(newArr2)
```